# Android Rest Architecture

Tags: android

My android application needs to communicate with a couple of Rest Services. Now i am decided to avoid using AsyncTasks for this. My architecture will be based on one Service and a couple of Intent Services. Each of my activity will send an intent containing parameters to a single service. Based on these parameters, the Service will invoke various IntentServices. The intent service will then perform the network operations and broadcast the result back into the calling activity. Is this approach correct ? Might be an idea for the Activity to directly invoke the IntentService ? What are the cons of this approach ?

Kind Regards

Comment: any reason why you don't want to work with AsyncTasks

Comment: Bad approch ... from what i hear. What do u say ?

Comment: @user1730789, Bad approach? Who've told you this?

Comment: does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) [FROM THE ANDROID DOCUMENTATION]

Comment: That's exactly what a REST webservice request is-  a quick HTTP request/response to a website is ideal for an AsyncTask.  You're over complicating things.

Comment: Services are not threads. Calling a bound service doesn't make it asynchronous - it still executes on the UI thread - unless the service is in another process, but then the UI thread blocks anyway.

Comment: AsyncTask is BAD for network calls. Since AsyncTask are strongly tied to your activity when the activity is destroyed, the AsyncTask will be destroyed. So, when you rotate your device, the Activity will be destroyed and also your AsyncTask, your network call will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Use robospice :)

Motivation :
http://thumbnails.visually.netdna-cdn.com/RoboSpice_508a372b320e5.png

Comment: I have looked at this. Seems very interesting. How stable is this ?

Answer (score 0):

the `WebApp` i.e. the REST service *should* answer with a `response` very quickly (so the client app doesn't lock). If your request takes some time to process, the `response` should be `202`. So you may have to look up that resource again, and that is indeed a nice job for `AsyncTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid) that implements the service pattern designed by Virgil Dobjanschi in the Google IO video